# How To use GHC.Generics to convert from product data types to a list of SqlValues and back

Tags: haskell, generics

I managed to use generics to create a default implementation for

```hs
class ToRow a where
  toRow :: a -> [SqlValue]
```

which works like expected. Now I'm struggling to write a generic default implementation for the inverse:

```hs
class FromRow a where
  fromRow :: [SqlValue] -> a
```

So here is the working `toRow` part:

```hs
import GHC.Generics
import Database.HDBC ( fromSql, toSql, SqlValue )
import Data.Convertible ( convert, ConvertResult, Convertible(..) )
import Data.Kind

class ToRow a where
  toRow :: a -> [SqlValue]

  default toRow :: Generic a => GToRow (Rep a) => a -> [SqlValue]
  toRow a = gtoRow $ from a

class GToRow f where
  gtoRow :: (f a) -> [SqlValue]

instance GToRow U1 where
  gtoRow U1 = mempty

instance (Convertible a SqlValue) => GToRow (K1 i a) where
  gtoRow (K1 a) = pure $ convert a

instance (GToRow a, GToRow b) => GToRow (a :*: b) where
  gtoRow (a :*: b) = gtoRow a `mappend` gtoRow b

instance GToRow a => GToRow (M1 i c a) where
  gtoRow (M1 a) = gtoRow a
```

And here comes the broken `fromRow` part:

```hs
class FromRow a where
  fromRow :: [SqlValue] -> a

  default fromRow :: GHC.Generics.Generic a => GFromRow (Rep a) => [SqlValue] -> a
  fromRow = to <$> gfromRow


class GFromRow f where
  gfromRow :: [SqlValue] -> f a

instance GFromRow U1 where
  gfromRow :: forall k (a :: k). [SqlValue] -> U1 a
  gfromRow = pure U1

instance (Convertible SqlValue a) => GFromRow (K1 i a) where
  gfromRow :: forall k (a1 :: k). [SqlValue] -> K1 i a a1
  gfromRow = K1 <$> convert . head    -- > Error: This uses just the first element of the [SqlValue] list

instance GFromRow a => GFromRow (M1 i c a) where
  gfromRow :: forall k (a :: k -> Type) i (c :: Meta) (a1 :: k). GFromRow a => [SqlValue] -> M1 i c a a1
  gfromRow = M1 <$> gfromRow

instance (GFromRow a, GFromRow b) => GFromRow (a :*: b) where
  gfromRow = (:*:) <$> gfromRow <*> gfromRow
```

I did not find a way to perform a conversion of the complete `[SqlValue]` in the `instance (Convertible SqlValue a) => GFromRow (K1 i a) where` implementation.

I`m testing this with the following demo code:

```hs
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int }
  deriving (Generic, Show, ToRow, FromRow)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let sqlValueList = toRow $ Person "John Doe" 30
  putStrLn $ "SQL values: " ++ show sqlValueList

  let person = fromRow sqlValueList :: Person
  putStrLn $ "Person: " ++ show person
```

Output in GHC is:

```
> main
SQL values: [SqlString "John Doe",SqlInt64 30]
Person: Person {name = "John Doe", age = *** Exception: Convertible: error converting source data SqlString "John Doe" of type SqlValue to type Int: Cannot read source value as dest type
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Data/Convertible/Base.hs:69:17 in convertible-1.1.1.1-1MxkWJFsBaiitSWznJamo:Data.Convertible.Base
```

So, how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have control of the `FromRow` class? If so, you can do what `postgresql-simple` does. Roughly: make it `fromRow :: State [SqlValue] a`; have each leaf pop one `SqlValue` from the current state; and then the `(:*:)` clause is just `liftA2 (:*:) fromRow fromRow`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea, Daniel! Yes, I have control of the FromRow class, as I'm in the middle of designing a persistence API (https://github.com/thma/generic-persistence). In fact I already  had a closer look at the postgresql-simple and sqlite-simple APIs. The Generics code for their RowParser based approach really looks compellingly simple, as you point out. But I prefer to have fromRow and toRow signatures symmetric to provide a more straight-forward user experience: `toRow :: a -> [SqlValue]` and `fromRow :: [SqlValue] -> a`. That's why I'm a happy camper with Li-yao's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the instance for `(:*:)`, you can split the row before passing it down in the recursive calls:

```
instance (KnownNat (NumFields f), GFromRow f, GFromRow g) => GFromRow (f :*: g) where
  gfromRow row = gfromRow rowf :*: gfromRow rowg
    where
      (rowf, rowg) = splitAt fNumFields row
      fNumFields = fromIntegral (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy (NumFields f)))
```

For that, you need to compute the number of fields in `f`. You can do so using a type family, and then turn it into a value using `KnownNat`/`natVal`.

```
type family NumFields (f :: Type -> Type) :: Nat where
  NumFields (M1 i c f) = 1
  NumFields (f :*: g) = NumFields f + NumFields g
```

Minimal compiling example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module C where

import Data.Kind
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.TypeNats

data SqlValue

class FromRow a where
  fromRow :: [SqlValue] -> a

class GFromRow f where
  gfromRow :: [SqlValue] -> f a

instance (KnownNat (NumFields f), GFromRow f, GFromRow g) => GFromRow (f :*: g) where
  gfromRow row = gfromRow rowf :*: gfromRow rowg
    where
      (rowf, rowg) = splitAt fNumFields row
      fNumFields = fromIntegral (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy (NumFields f)))

type family NumFields (f :: Type -> Type) :: Nat where
  NumFields (M1 i c f) = 1
  NumFields (f :*: g) = NumFields f + NumFields g
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, that works like a charm!
I was looking in the wrong spot and not in the `GFromRow (f :*: g)` clause!